# trying to get assembleRelease react-native

Tags: react-native

So far, I have not had any problems getting the output of the application, but now
I'm trying to get assembleRelease and show me this error:

```
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-screens:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-screens
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.     
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

this is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.1",
    "i18next": "^21.5.3",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.14.3",
    "react-native": "^0.66.3",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-native": "^6.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Bin tray is experiencing "intermittent issues" on their download network :

https://status.bintray.com/

Also if you are using obselete **jCenter**(), then replace it with **mavenCentral**() in your **android/build.gradle**